# How to parse data from a website page with no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header (JS)?

Tags: javascript, dom, cors, fetch

I want to parse a marketplace page using a fetch request. To be more precise: I have a list of product names (not shown in the code extract below, but it exists elsewhere), and for each of these names I want to find the products with max and min prices. After these products are found, I want to retrieve the price with sale, price without sale, product name and a link to that product.

Below is a part of the code where I try to fetch the data described above. The marketplace server is however configured in such a way that Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not set for the localhost (on which my project is currently running) - so I end up in CORS policy blocking my request to the server.

```
async function findProductWithMinOrMaxPriceWb(productName, mode = "min") {
  const sortMethods = ["priceup", "pricedown"];
  let link;
  let query;

  mode === "min"
    ? (query = `https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/0/search.aspx?sort=${sortMethods[0]}&search=${productName}`)
    : (query = `https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/0/search.aspx?&sort=${sortMethods[1]}&search=${productName}`) &&
      (mode = "max");

  return fetch(query)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((html) => {
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const htmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
      const product = htmlDocument.documentElement.querySelector(
        ".product-card-list > article > div > a"
      );
      link = product.href;
      return fetch(link); // to retrieve price and name we have to go to another url
    })
    .then((html) => {
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const htmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

      const name = htmlDocument.documentElement.querySelector(
        ".product-page__header > h1"
      ).innerHTML;
      const priceWithSale = htmlDocument.documentElement.querySelector(
        ".price-block__final-price"
      ).innerHTML;
      const priceWithoutSale = htmlDocument.documentElement.querySelector(
        ".price-block__old-price"
      ).innerHTML;

      return [name, priceWithSale, priceWithoutSale, link];
    });
}
```

As a result I get an expected error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/0/search.aspx?sort=priceup&search=Frosch. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

However using DevTools and entering FETCH/XHR section I managed to find the URL fetching which I receive all the stuff I need except for link to the product with max/min price. This is better than nothing but still not a solution for me.

That brings me to the initial question: if there is any way to bypass the CORS and read the desired data from the page like I tried in the code above?

Comment: Some browsers may have an option to disable CORS policy enforcement.  Alternatively you could proxy the requests through a server you control.  Or you could not use a browser in the first place and fetch the data from an application (which could still be JavaScript, using NodeJS for example).